# How to run only certain intermediate operations in parallel in Java-8?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I am trying to mimic the behaviour of `WireTap` in `Spring Integration` & `Apache Camel` in java8 stream, where a copy of current processing data is passed to `WireTap` for processing it in a separate thread, it would be helpful for logging & auditing

Here I want only the logging in `peek` want to run on separate thread

```
List<String> lines = ...

List<String> upperLines = lines.stream()
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .parallel() // which is hidden by the sequential
    .peek(line -> System.out.println(line)) // don't want to run this fully on main thread
    .sequential()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Should I need to implement a separate method using `BlockingQueue` or `ExecutorService` for doing this

```
.peek(this::logger)
```

Comment: note that  although you called `.parallel()` the stream will still run sequentially due to the call `.sequential()` being the last of the two.

Comment: @Aominè yes the last `sequential` or `parallel` wins

Comment: You cannot do this with a `Stream`. Push events into a `BlockingQueue` with `peek` and then have another thread publish them. Note that asynchronous logging is tricky - what happens if the state of the object being logged changes?

Comment: Long story short: you cant, its an *entire* pipeline either parallel or sequential

Comment: To expand upon @Eugene comment, this is because internally, a boolean flag is set to signal that you want to run in parallel all the operations that follow the invocation to parallel or all the operations following the invocation to sequential, hence the last call to parallel or sequential to set the flag wins. I don't see how you can do this with Streams IMO.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question a little? I personally don't fully understand what exactly you want to achieve. In particular, do you want some elements being processed in parallel, others in sequential, or what?

Comment: It's worth noting that when designing Streams, we explored the option of allowing portions of a pipeline to be parallel and others sequential.  This turned out to be a loser in nearly every dimension -- not only did it dramatically increase the complexity of the implementation, but there were very few cases where it actually paid off in performance.

Comment: If you want to ensure that elements are not processed concurrently, you can end the stream with `forEachOrdered()`.  But unless your intermediate operations are insanely expensive, you are probably better off running sequential in that case.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. You can do `List<String> upperLines = lines .parallelStream() .map(String::toUpperCase) .peek(System.out::println) .collect(Collectors.toList());` and it will do the right thing, you won’t even notice the difference to your desired the mixed execution. Besides that, you can also do `List<String> upperLines = lines.stream() .map(String::toUpperCase) .collect(Collectors.toList()); upperLines .parallelStream() .forEach(System.out::println);` to truly have only the printing in parallel, but, as said, without noticing an actual difference.

Comment: @Holger instead of iterating on the computed result in stream1, while processing the stream for the first time itself, I thought to make auditing on separate thread

Comment: You still don’t notice a difference, as “while” or “after” are meaningless in concurrent programming. Triggering the logging from `peek` still doesn’t prevent the stream’s completion while the logging is still ongoing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to process parts of a stream pipeline in a different mode and it wouldn’t pay off to implement such mixed mode pipeline, given, how simple submitting an asynchronous job is on your side:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
List<String> upperLines = lines.stream()
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .peek(line -> es.execute(() -> System.out.println(line)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
es.shutdown();
```

or

```
List<String> upperLines = lines.stream()
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .peek(line -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println(line)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
// when running this in the main method, avoid JVM termination before the async jobs:
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

But note that in this specific case, there is actually no perceivable difference to, e.g.

```
List<String> upperLines = lines.stream()
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
upperLines.parallelStream().forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));
```

or, if you do not want to wait for the completion of the logging statement:

```
List<String> upperLines = lines.stream()
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
upperLines.forEach(line -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println(line)));
```